# Phone numbers links not working on Android 9

Tags: android, kotlin, android-9.0-pie

I want to have my phone number to be clickable, right now my current solution:

```
final SpannableString msg = "Contact us: test@t.t or call: 5008 878 6578"
Linkify.addLinks(msg, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
textView.setText(msg);
```

This works fine for Android 8.1 and below but not for Android 9 (email is clickable so the problem is only with number phone)

I've tried already doing it with XML layouts or with

```
textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS)
```

And the output is the same, phone number is not clickable.

How to fix it on Android 9?

Comment: does it work when you remove the spaces from the phone number?

Comment: @ZUNJAE still not working even without spaces. I've also tried different formats but the output is always the same

Comment: your phone number should be in correct format. for example like this: +989354058789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask `Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS` seems correct, according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/util/Linkify.html#phone_numbers) - but I would not recognize something alike `5008 878 6578` as a valid phone number - and I definitely could not dial it, if I would click it... so most likely the `sPhoneNumberMatchFilter` might be at fault.
Manually building the desired `Spannable` with the `tel://50088786578` might be an easy solution; adjusting the `sPhoneNumberMatchFilter` might be the other option... also [.addLinks()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addlinks_9) permits this, with argument `matchFilter`.

Are you certain that you are running with the same `Locale` on Android 9.0? This should be where the regex pattern to match for may come from, because those formats count towards localization.